# http.query text_out is written to console

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to use the http.query state in saltstack in order
to download some tgz archive through an api.

Through text_out I was able to write the respone data into
a file which is great, however the file contents (the response
data) is also written to the output. This is problematic
because it spams the output with tgz nonsense- which
in turn partly hide the meaningful output (the state status)
as well.

Do you know of a way to hide the response, something like
quiet?

Originally I tried using archive.extracted, however the api
I'm using requires an authentication and I couldn't find a 
way to make it work that way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `text=False` if `text_out` is set,

```
text=False,
text_out='/tmp/text'
```

more on [http.query()](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/http.html#salt-utils-http-query)